# Will the magnetic lines close as depicted? 3-d horse-shoe magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Consider the iron shape with grey in the following figure.

[image]

Assume an electric current is ran as shown. Will the generated magnetic lines look as depicted? This wants to be a 3-d version of the "horse-shoe" magnet ... Is this correct?